# What is wrong with addTarget in Swift 4

Tags: swift

Error says:

> Use of local variable 'SwtchChange(Parametr:)' before its declaration

Please, what do I need to change?

```
mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SwtchChange(Parametr:)), for: .valueChanged)

func SwtchChange(Parametr: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn {
        print ("Yeah")
    } else {
        print ("Nope")
    }
```

Comment: Show this code in some context.

Comment: Not related to your issue but all variable, function, and parameter names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Where did you put exactly the code of `addTarget()`?

Comment: Don't you need `@objc` for selectors?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is about declaring your function in the same scope where you try to add your target.

If you somehow managed to declare function inside a viewDidLoad or somewhere else, first you need to move the function to the class level, and then add @objc to the beginning of your func.

Assuming you add your target and declare func in same scope, please modify your code like below and move method declaration to outer scope:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swtchChange), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func swtchChange(parametr: UISwitch) {
    if parametr.isOn {
        print ("Yeah")
    } else {
        print ("Nope")
    }
}
```

Also it is better to declare your function name starting lowercase as mentioned in the comments so I edited your function name as `swtchChange` from `SwtchChange`. Also the parameter name updated and used within method scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Use of local variable 'SwtchChange(Parametr:)' before its declaration

You're getting this error because you have method embed in another method after you call it (`viewDidLoad` probably)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    mySwitch.addTarget(mySwitch, action: #selector(SwtchChange(Parametr:)), for: .valueChanged)

    func SwtchChange(Parametr: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch.isOn {
            print ("Yeah")
        } else {
            print ("Nope")
        }
    }
}
```

Don't do this, your target method should be declared in *global scope* of your view controller, and since you're using `Selector`, you have to mark your method as `@objc`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(parameter:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func switchChanged(parameter: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch.isOn {
            print("Yeah")
        } else {
            print("Nope")
        }
    }

}
```

... also note that names of **variables/methods** should start with **small** capital letter and names of **types** with **big** capital letter

Answer (score 0):

When using selectors in Swift you need to make sure the func is marks with @objc. Try this:

```
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
           print ("Yeah")
        } else {
           print ("Nope")
        }
    }
```